# Bluetooth headset playthrough in Mac OSx

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio

I am developing an audio playthrough application by using the apple sample code CAPlayThrough.
This sample code works fine for all audio devices except bluetooth headset.
How can we send audio data to a bluetooth device. Could any one show me some pointer on this.